# Retention period Changes in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

Can I change the Retention period from my original set date of 10 days (which was set to this months ago) to 14 or more days in the properties tool without causing problems.

SQL Server 2014

Comment: retention period of what?

Comment: Retention period for Change Tracking in SQL server 2014